# Googlesearch via VBA in MS-Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, serverxmlhttp

following code-snippet searches with google search for company-names. this code is working in excel:

```
    Dim el                      As Object
    Dim http                    As Object
    Dim html                    As New HTMLDocument
    
    Dim lng_row_start As Long
    Dim lng_row As Long
    Dim lng_row_new As Long
    Dim int_column_name As Integer
    Dim int_column_news As Integer
    
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    '------------
    str_sheet = "news"
    lng_row_start = 3
    int_column_name = 1
    int_column_news = 3
    '------------
    lng_row = lng_row_start
    lng_row_new = lng_row_start
    Do While 0 < Len(Sheets(str_sheet).Cells(lng_row, int_column_name).Value)
    
        str_google = Replace(Sheets(str_sheet).Cells(lng_row, int_column_name).Value, " ", "+")
        http.Open "GET", "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & str_google & "&tbm=nws", False
        http.send
        html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
        '--------
        Set el = html.getElementById("rso")
```

now i want to do that in access.
using XMLHTTP gives me "no permission"-error on the "http.send"-line.
using ServerXMLHTTP gives me a responseText saying that i got the "error 403. client has no permission to get url".

now i added this line for the ServerXMLHTTP:

```
http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1)"
```

now i get an responseText saying something about "signing in/login". im german so it tells me "Anmelden".

so i still cant get the google-search result.

some ideas? maybe how i get a correct requestHeader so i dont get the "login" responseText?

i use ms-access 2007-20016.

following is my access code snippet:

```
On Error GoTo err_stan
'DEFINITION
    Dim str_google      As String
    Dim el2             As New HTMLDocument
    Dim el3             As New HTMLDocument
    Dim el4             As New HTMLDocument
    Dim el              As New HTMLDocument
    Dim http            As Object
    Dim html            As New HTMLDocument
    Dim db              As DAO.Database
    Dim rs_companies    As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rs_news         As DAO.Recordset
'DECLARATION
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs_companies = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT companyName FROM qGoogleSearch")
    Set rs_news = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Tnews")
    'Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
'ALGORITHM
    rs_companies.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs_companies.EOF
    
        str_google = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & _
                    Replace(rs_companies.Fields("companyName").Value, " ", "+") & _
                    "&tbm=nws"
        'http.SetOption 2, 13056
        http.Open "GET", str_google, False
        'http.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+5.1)"
        http.send
        html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
        
        Set el = html.getElementById("rso")
```

EDIT:
using this url works:
https://www.google.com/search?q=bango+plc

this does give a permission error:
https://www.google.com/search?q=bango+plc&tbm=nws
in excel it works fine...

why does XMLHTTP work in excel but not in access?
i tried to put the msaccess-file in a trusted location. did not work

Comment: Access has no `Sheets`, so you should edit the question to hold your actual code.

Comment: I tested code with that problem line active and don't get the error nor the 'login' prompt.

Comment: a 'prompt'? i read the responseText and there is something with 'login'. do you get the element with ID=rso in the last line?

Comment: Ooops, I thought 'get in ResponseText' meant you were prompted for some input. If not, how is this relevant? No, does not 'get' element rso. "Object variable not set" error.

Comment: I did a search in Word of the responseText string and there is no rso element. There is an hdr element and I tested setting object with that element and it works. No idea what element needs to be referenced to get desired results. All code examples I can find are several years old - perhaps something has changed. Neither of the static URL strings work for me.

Comment: Well, just tested code in Excel VBA and it does find element rso even though search in Word does not find it. Bizarre!

Comment: there is normaly an rso element in every googlesearch html-code. in excel i get the correct html but in access i get an html with that login thing. also in access i have to use ServerXMLHTTP. in excel i use XMLHTTP. either way, im thankfull for your response and tryout!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update try this and report back:

This is what works for me:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' How To Write To A File
Set File = FSO.CreateTextFile("C:\Foobar.html",True)
File.Write cstr(http("GET", "https://www.google.com/search?q=bango+plc&tbm=nws", "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", ""))
File.Close

Set FSO = Nothing
Set File = Nothing

call MsgBox(http("GET", "https://www.google.com/search?q=bango+plc&tbm=nws", "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", ""))



''MsgBox(httpGet("https://localhost:5001/api/departments?pageNumber=1&pageSize=1", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8", "application/xml"))
Sub httpGet(sUrl, sRequestHeaderContentType, sRequestHeaderAccept)
    Call http("GET", sUrl, sRequestHeaderContentType, sRequestHeaderAccept, "")
End Sub



''MsgBox(httpPost("https://localhost:5001/api/departments?userfriendlyName=987Junk", "application/xml; charset=UTF-8", "application/xml", ""))
Sub httpPost(sUrl,sRequestHeaderContentType, sRequestHeaderAccept, sbody)
    Call http("POST", sRequestHeaderContentType, sRequestHeaderAccept, sbody)
End Sub

Function http(httpCommand, sUrl, sRequestHeaderContentType, sRequestHeaderAccept, sbody)
        Err.Clear
        Dim oXML 'AS XMLHTTP60
        'Set oXML = CreateObject("msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
        Set oXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        Dim aErr
        
    On Error Resume Next
        Call oXML.Open(CStr(httpCommand), CStr(sUrl), False)
        'oXML.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0"
        oXML.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.114 Safari/537.36"
        'oXML.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic base64encodeduserandpassword"
        oXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", CStr(sRequestHeaderContentType)
        'oXML.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        oXML.setRequestHeader "CharSet", "charset=UTF-8"
        'oXML.setRequestHeader "Accept", "*/*"
        oXML.setRequestHeader "Accept", CStr(sRequestHeaderAccept)
        oXML.setRequestHeader "cache-control", "no-cache"
        oXML.setRequestHeader "sec-ch-ua","Google Chrome;v=89, Chromium;v=89, ;Not A Brand;v=99"
        
        aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description)

    On Error Goto 0
         If 0 = aErr(0) Then
    On Error Resume Next
                Call oXML.send(sbody)
                aErr = Array(Err.Number, Err.Description)
    On Error Goto 0
                Select Case True
                    Case 0 <> aErr(0)
                        Trace("send failed: " & CStr(aErr(0)) & " " & CStr(aErr(1)))
                    Case 200 = oXML.status
                        'Trace(sUrl & "    HttpStatusCode:" & oXML.status & "    HttpStatusText:" & oXML.statusText)
                        http = oXML.responseText
                    Case 201 = oXML.status
                        Trace(sUrl & "    HttpStatusCode:" & oXML.status & "    HttpStatusText:" & oXML.statusText)
                    Case Else
                        Trace("further work needed:")
                        Trace("URL:" & CStr(sUrl) & "      Message Status:" & CStr(oXML.status) & "      Message Text:" & CStr(oXML.statusText))
                        Trace("further work needed:")
                End Select
        Else
            Trace("open failed: " & CStr(aErr(0)) & " " & CStr(aErr(1)))
        End If
    
    'httpPost.HttpStatusCode = cstr(oXML.status)
    'httpPost.HttpStatusText = cstr(oXML.statusText)
    'httpPost.responseText = cstr(oXML.responseText)
    
    Set oXML = Nothing
End Function

Function Trace(Message1)
    MsgBox(Message1)
End Function
```

Comment: i tried to use your "httpGET" function but i get "further work is needed" - "status:403 text: forbidden"

Comment: What is an example url you are passing? 
 https://www.google.com/search?q=???&tbm=nws
What is your return media type? Html, json, xml, or something else?

Comment: The 403 is coming from google, I had to add some and update some heades but my example is working.

Comment: sorry for late feedback. doing that in freetime only and had some issues to attend. I think my return media is html. I look for html-code from the website (google news search) and I put it in an xmlhttp object. I am looking for an element with ID="rso" in that html-code. Unfortunately I do not find that element. with your approach. If I do a normal google search, it is fine. If i do a google >news< search, I dont get the correct html-responseText. It should be google-related. Also now it is not working in excel anymore. I guess it is header-related but i dont know much about that.

Comment: so your approach kinda works as i dont get an error. but i still cant find the element ID="rso". every google search has this element, I just checked it manually in my browser: did a random google search, right-click, examine, code opens and i found the "rso"-element

Comment: In my results I have a id="rso". Maybe you should post a very stripped-down version of your access database. You can create it on GitHub or something like that. That way I can look at what you are trying to do and just fix the problem. If you would like you can also add the excel file as well.

Comment: I created a repository for the files I created. If you add your files to this folder and do a PR I will except PR and make appropriate changes. 
 https://github.com/CTGControls/StackOverFlowExamples/tree/main/67042233

Comment: So I looked at your code there are two things going on 1) The document is too large for a string in VBA (There is a maximum of 32768 characters for any string) This maybe why you are missing results.  2) I don't think HTMLDocument fully supports HTML5. The only way I can see to do what you are asking is to write your own com dll. If you would like to open a new Question and post the link here I can help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

XMLHTTP (the client object) is not permitted to access remote objects (viruses) unless the scripting host is trusted. So the reason Access is given a permission error is because it hasn't told XMLHTTP that it has that permission.

I don't know more about XMLHTTP trust settings. See if the Trust Center (Access) helps.

Comment: thanks for the repliy. i tried to put it in a trusted location and activate all macros, activex-elements without warning etc. did not help, may i missed something..